# Bootstrap Ordering Elements by Screen Size

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, grid

Am I losing my mind, because I'm absolutely sure this code should work... but it doesn't.

I'm trying to order my elements according to screen size ie. if `small` screen or less, menu element is first - and if `medium` screen or more - menu element is second.

```
<div class="col-md-9 order-sm-2 order-md-1">
Main content
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 order-sm-1 order-md-2">
Menu column
</div>
```

What I'm getting for both `small` and `medium` screen size is: Main content (1st) and Menu column (2nd).

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is either that `order-sm-2` and `order-sm-1` should define the `xs` instead of `sm` versions,

or that the shown code isn't surrounded by the same `row` & `container` DIVs

Answer (score 0):

I'm such a div (no pun intended):

```
<div class="col-md-9 order-2 order-md-1">
Main content
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 order-1 order-md-2">
Menu column
</div>
```

Needed to have a base `order` before introducing a breakpoint.

Comment: Yea that's another way of doing the same as making the SM to XS change i detailed. The bigger screen sizes are media blocks with tighter constraints than their smaller counterparts, in other words XL is a subset of LG, LG is a a subset of MD, and so on all the way down to XS. Because of this, when you define a value for XS (the smallest), it automatically also applies to all the bigger sizes. If you then define a value for MD that value will only affect MD/LG/XL sizes as the others (XS/SM) aren't subsets of MD.